# Login into an EC2 instance as root user

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, root, ansible-playbook

I am trying to run the following ansible playbook against an AWS EC2 instance. I need to run that script as **root** user in order to access the docker engine. I dynamically populate the `builders` hosts group before running the playbook.

```
- name: Create saronia/teamcity-server image
  hosts: builders[0]
  become: True
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: root
  tasks:
  ...
```

Yet, no matter what I try I get the following error:

**`Please login as the user \"admin\" rather than the user \"root\".`**

What's possible to do is:

- `ssh admin@{{ public_ip }}`
- ´sudo -i´
- `docker info`

However, what I need is being able to run a ansible playbook:

`ansible-playbook create_docker_image.yml`

What is necessary to run an ansible script as **root** user against a machine I own? Please, someone enlighten me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect as a non-privileged user and use become to change to root:

```
become: True
become_user: root
vars:
    ansible_user: admin
```

Ansible >= 2.0 has deprecated the "ssh" from the connection options. root is the default become user, but you may specify it in case the default was changed.